# Python: Error in assigning a method result to a instance variable on a constructor

Tags: python, list, constructor

When I run this code I get a message saying that name 'readFile' is not defined. How can I write this so that I don't have this error? I want to assign a list of lists to self.cities. Thank you.

```
class TSP:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.cities = readFile()

    def readFile(self):   
        f = open(self.filename, 'r')
        citieslist = []
        res = f.readlines()
        for line in res:
            aList = list(line.split(';'))
            for i in range(0,len(aList)):
                aList[i] = aList[i].rstrip('\n')
            citieslist.append(aList)
        return readFile (self.cities)
        f.close()
```

Comment: call `self.readFile(...)` instead of `readFile(...)` within your class methods.

Comment: I missed the recursive call.   Your return statement is incorrect and in the wrong place.   First do `f.close()`, then simply `return citieslist`, which I believe was your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not used `self` in `init`. You have a recursive function at `readFile`. You closed the file after returning from function `readFile`. You only have to strip the whole line to cut the `\n` off. Also returning is unnecessary since you can work with references inside `Class`.

```
class TSP:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.cities = self.readFile()

    def readFile(self):   
        f = open(self.filename, 'r')
        citieslist = []
        res = f.readlines()
        for city in res:
            city = city.strip().split(';')
            citieslist.append(city)
        f.close()
        return citieslist
```

Comment: That's not the case, it's proper PEP8.

Comment: Ok, then provide a short answer without explanation which he could not understand well. So much better.

Comment: I didn't have to explain everything the questioner got wrong because I didn't use any of it. Instead, I simply showed them how to do it right. They obviously already understand how to open a file so, changing that part to `with` shouldn't be a mystery. They were already looping over `readlines()` so, the `list comprehension` shouldn't be a mystery either. Assuming they can't understand incredibly short and easy to read code is your issue, not mine.

Comment: Why do you think I don't understand what you are talking about? Care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

SInce you have basically negated any future use of `readFile` by omitting an argument for `filename` in it's interface, you could just do the below.

We simply use a `with` statement to process the file, and a `list comprehension` to concoct the results.

```
class TSP:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            self.cities = [line.strip().split(';') for line in f.readlines()]

        #do something with self.cities here
    
                
tsp = TSP('somefile.ext')
```